# (How) does file buffering in C work on bidirectional non-seekable files?

Tags: c++, c, io, buffer

I've looked at some imlementations on file buffering and they seem to work by having one buffer that alters between being a read buffer and write buffer (and keeping track of this). To me this seem to require that you're able to seek in the file (when you change direction of the operations).

(How) does this work if you have a stream that doesn't support seeking?

To me it seems that you can't discard data read into the buffer which means that you can't share the memory for read and write buffer. So perhaps in such a case you would need to have two buffers?

Is there a difference between C and C++ regarding the capabilities of the file buffering?

Comment: Having one single buffer for both reading and writing makes no sense. It doesn't matter if the stream is seekable or not, when mixing reading from and writing to the stream, having a single combined buffer just won't work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank's, but it would kind of work if the underlying file conforms to the "normal" file behavior (the buffer then would just be a window of the underlying data). Why I assumed a single buffer is that `setbuf` is only supplied one buffer. Do you say that this memory region is partitioned into two buffers?

Comment: A single contiguous memory area (like an array) can be used as *two* buffers, just use one half for the input and one for the output. If this is what the C `FILE*` functions does I don't know. But if you think a little, lets say you read one some data from a file using e.g. `fread`, write some data using `fwrite`, and then again read using `fread`. Yes it can be done with a single shared buffer, if it is flushed between the calls. It's not effective though, and C I/O (and C standard functions in general) are pretty much all about efficiency.

Comment: And even if it's technically undefined behavior, you can actually test how the buffer you set using e.g. `setvbuf` is used, by checking the contents. Read and write some known data from and to a file, and then dump the contents of your custom buffer. You can also use system-call trace program to see if a flush is done of the buffer between writing and reading.

Comment: Are you referring to `STDIO`-based functionality?  If so, for files opened in update mode, the C Standard specifically states "output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function".  Those calls either flush unwritten data in the buffer, or discard buffered but unread data.  I can't find any mention in the C Standard regarding their behavior on non-seekable streams.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Does it really say that those calls discards buffered but unread data? If it's done even on failure (or if "call" means a successful call) of those it would imply what should happen on non-seekable streams.

Comment: @skyking It's at least strongly implied by "After determining the new position, a successful call to the
`fseek`
function undoes any
effects of the
`ungetc`
function on the stream, clears the end-of-file indicator for the
stream, and then establishes the new position. After a successful `fseek` call, the next operation on an update stream may be either input or output." Because if you can do *either* input or output, there can be no data in the buffer, and "undoing the effects of `ungetc`" means discarding buffered data. It may also be explicitly stated elsewhere, but I haven't found it.